# Matplotlib Boxplot and pandas dataframe data type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

So I set up this empty dataframe DF and load data into the dataframe according to some conditions. As such, some its elements would then be empty (`nan`). I noticed that if I don't specify the datatype as float when I create the empty dataframe, `DF.boxplot()` will give me an 'Index out of range' error.

As I understand it, pandas' `DF.boxplot()` uses matplotlib's `plt.boxplot()` function, so naturally I tried using plt.boxplot(DF.iloc[:,0]) to plot the boxplot of the first column. I noticed a reversed behavior: When dtype of DF is float, it will not work: it will just show me an empty plot.  See the code below where `DF.boxplot()` wont work, but `plt.boxplot(DF.iloc[:,0])` will plot a boxplot (when i add dtype='float' when first creating the dataframe, `plt.boxplot(DF.iloc[:,0])` will give me an empty plot):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

DF=pd.DataFrame(index=range(10),columns=range(4))
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(4):
        if i==j:
         continue
        DF.iloc[i,j]=i
```

I am wondering does this has to do with how `plt.boxplot()` handles nan for different data types? If so, why did setting the dataframe's data type as 'object' didn't work for `DF.boxplot()`, if pandas is just using matplotlib's boxplot function?

Comment: added some codes that reproduce my problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think we can agree that neither `df.boxplot()` nor `plt.boxplot` can handle dataframes of type "object". Instead they need to be of a numeric datatype.

If the data is numeric, `df.boxplot()` will work as expected, even with `nan` values, because they are removed before plotting.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame(index=range(10),columns=range(4), dtype=float)
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(4):
        if i!=j:
            df.iloc[i,j]=i

df.boxplot()
plt.show()
```

Using `plt.boxplot` you would need to remove the `nan`s manually, e.g. using `df.dropna()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame(index=range(10),columns=range(4), dtype=float)
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(4):
        if i!=j:
            df.iloc[i,j]=i
data = [df[i].dropna() for i in range(4)]
plt.boxplot(data)
plt.show()
```

To summarize:[image]

Comment: Thanks, I just realized even though `plt.boxplot()` will give me a plot with `dtype='object'`, it will still return an error.